# Ruby on Rails - Double association database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, associations

I have this situation :

```
user.rb
has_many :games

item.rb
has_many :games

game.rb
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
belongs_to :item, :foreign_key => 'item_id'


Item :
id : 13 | name : "Foo"

User :
id : 1 | name : "Me"

Game :
id : 1 | user_id : 4 | item_id : 13
id : 2 | user_id : 1 | item_id : 13
id : 3 | user_id : 2 | item_id : 2
id : 4 | user_id : 1 | item_id : 13
....
```

This works :

```
item=Item.find(13)
user=User.find(1)

user.games (returns all games with the user_id == 1)
item.games (return all games with item_id == 13)
```

But now I want all games for the user 1 and with the item 13, how do I do ? This doesn't work :

```
user.item.games
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship between the user and item?  Please mention the relationship between all three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Game.where(user_id: 1, item_id:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the associations you used in each of the models, this will help us answer your question.

did you try, in your user.rb (User model) adding the association:

```
has_many :games
has_many :items, through: :games
```

Then you would get all the items is all the games the user has like this:

```
user.items
```

or, **for the very specific search you are looking for**, you could add a **scope** to the games model, at **game.rb**:

```
scope :with_user, -> (user_id) { where(user_id: user_id) }
scope :with_item, -> (item_id) { where(item_id: item_id) }
```

then you could write a specific search with:

```
Game.with_user(1).with_item(13)
```

I didn't test any of this, you will have to see what works for you according to your needs.

I would read more about scopes at [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since , a game has both user_id and a item_id, I believe there should be a relationship between the user and the item too. As pointed out by @Myst above, a has_many-through relationship is ideal in this case. That is:
In User Model:

```
has_many :games
has_many :items, through: :games
```

In your games model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :item
```

Implement that in your models and then you can try

```
user.games.where(:item_id => 13)
```

If you also want something like this:

```
item.users.where(:user_id => 1)
```

then implement a similar relationship in your items model too ie:

```
has_many :games
has_many :users, through: :games
```